# Python Simulation Patient-Doctor Link (Simpy, Emergency Department)

Tags: python, simulation, agent-based-modeling, simpy, queueing

I'm working on a project to describe the patient flow in the Emergency Department using Simpy 2.6.

Suppose there are three doctors in the intake area. My process is, after seeing one specific doctor (say, doctor X), the patient will (with 80% chance) go to the lab. After the lab test, the patient will return back to the original doctor X by rejoining the queue.

But how can i create a link between the patient-docotr? Right now the patients in my code is "memoryless" - they just see a random doctor after the lab test. There are 20 beds in total in the intake area.

Please help me! Thank you in advance!!

```
class Intake(Process):
    Queue = [] #patient queue
    Idle = [] #idle PAs list
    Busy = [] #busy PAs list
    Waits=[] #list of wait times, the D2D time
    #Wholetime=[] #list of whole time spent in ED
    IQ = [] #amount in queue when a customer leaves
    NDone = 0 #total number of customers that have been services 
    i = 0 #new; counter of bed occupation 
    def __init__(self):
        Process.__init__(self)
        Intake.Idle.append(self) #initially idle 
    def Run(self):
        while Intake.i <= 20: # new new new bed 
            yield passivate,self #remain idle until customer is ready 
            Intake.Idle.remove(self)
            Intake.Busy.append(self)

            while Intake.Queue != []: #perform while customers in queue
                P = Intake.Queue.pop(0) # get customer 
                Intake.i += 1  #new new new  bed
                Intake.ServiceRate1 = 0.1 / (P.Severity)
                Intake.Waits.append(now() - P.ArrivalTime)
                Intake.IQ.append(len(Intake.Queue)) 
                ServiceTime = G.Rnd.expovariate(Intake.ServiceRate1) 
                yield hold,self,ServiceTime #perform job 
                Intake.NDone += 1 

                if rand() <=  0.8:
                    Lab.Queue.append(P)
                    if Lab.Idle != []:
                       reactivate(Lab.Idle[0])
                else:
                    Treatment.Queue.append(P)
                    Intake.i -= 1
                    if Treatment.Idle != []:
                       reactivate(Treatment.Idle[0])

            Intake.Busy.remove(self) 
            Intake.Idle.append(self)

""" Lab Process (with P=0.8 patients come here)"""  
class Lab(Process):

    Queue = [] #patient queue
    Idle = [] #idle PAs list
    Busy = [] #busy PAs list
    Wholetime=[] #list of whole time spent in ED
    #Waits=[] #list of wait times, the D2D time
    #hQ = [] #amount in queue when a customer leaves
    NDone = 0 #total number of customers that have been services 
    def __init__(self):
        Process.__init__(self)
        Lab.Idle.append(self) #initially idle 
    def Run(self):
        while True:
            yield passivate,self #remain idle until customer is ready 
            Lab.Idle.remove(self)
            Lab.Busy.append(self)
            while Lab.Queue != []: #perform while customers in queue
                P = Lab.Queue.pop(0) # get customer 
                #Lab.hQ.append(len(Lab.Queue))
                ServiceRate2 = 1.0/(P.Severity) #service rate is recipricol of mean service time  #### for Lab
                ServiceTime = G.Rnd.expovariate(ServiceRate2) 
                Lab.Wholetime.append(now() - P.ArrivalTime + ServiceTime)
                yield hold,self,ServiceTime #perform job 
                #Lab.Wholetime.append(now() - P.Arriv)
                Lab.NDone += 1  
                Intake.i -= 1   ## new new new bed 
            Lab.Busy.remove(self) 
            Lab.Idle.append(self)
```

Comment: There is no SimPy 2.6. Also, if your project just started, you should consider moving to SimPy 3. It’s much more powerful and you will get better support.